# How to subtract a value of a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to do something like that:

```
var hands_original =$(".sw_3--breit").position();
var hands_corrected = hands_original.top - 300px;
```

where I want to retrieve the y-coordinates value subtracted with 300px.
How would I correctly write that? What is the difference with other values like "vh" or "%"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you tried to calculate a number with a string, and that would not work well. So calculate the `top` with the value and then concatenate `"px"`

```js
var hands_original =$(".sw_3--breit").position();
var hands_corrected = (hands_original.top - 300) + "px";
console.log(hands_corrected);


$("button").click(function() {
  $(".sw_3--breit").css("top", hands_corrected)
})
```

```css
.sw_3--breit{
  position: fixed;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
}

body {height: 1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sw_3--breit">.sw_3--breit</div>

<button>move</button>
```